# How can I stop RefineryCMS from adding <p> tags around text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I created a controller for "products" to be added into my app that is utilizing the Refinery CMS.

Hhere is the code for the page in `show.html.erb`

```
<div>
  <h3>Feedback Sought</h3>
  <p>
    <%=raw @product.description %>
  </p>
</div>
```

But this is what is actually produced in the live page. 

[image: dynamic code]

For the meantime I can implement a digsuting hack of removing the margin by targeting the element, like

```
.productFeedbackDescription p { margin: 0; }
```

and then doing inline css along the lines of

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 12px;">
  <%=raw @product.description %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Refinery adds `<p>` tags in the template.

And by default, using the WYSIWYG editor also adds `<p>` tags. So I manually removed the `<p>` tags from the template.

For reference, this was the default code generated by refinery when I create the controller

```
<section>
  <h1>Product Summary</h1>
  <p>
    <%=raw @product.product %>
  </p>
</section>
```

Now my code is

```
<div>
  <h3>Product Summary</h3>
  <%=raw @product.product %>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the code now generated as live in page.

[image: page now]